# Why is my UITableView not correctly expanding my cells?

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have set up a `UITableView` (with the appropriate delegate and datasource) in the exact same way that I have set up all of the other table views in my application, yet these individual cells appear to be acting differently. There are no constraints in place, and this is what the table looks like in the story board:
[image]
And yet, when I go to run the simulator, the cells cut off all of the content, as if they are not sticking to the orientation I have laid out, as seen in the next picture:
[image]
Not sure why this is.

Comment: No constraints is the reason...

Comment: Most if not all of the UITableViews in my application were initially set up without explicit constrains and did not behave like this; all cells at least displayed all of the information that was displayed in the storyboard

Comment: can you share tableview delegate method ?

Comment: if so, you want to manual layout, then please adopt the table view delegate and implement tableviewHeight(indexPath:) -> CGFloat method(dont remeber the exact the name)

Comment: @RB1509 do you mean like the `cellForRowatIndexpath`?

Comment: @MatthewLuiHK why did I not need to do that for any of my other tableviews?

Comment: @RB1509 can you please elaborate? I'm still having this issue

Comment: maybe on your other tableview, you’ve assign a static height for all cell, but for this one first the static height is not set therefore it use default value which is 47(as i remember), second since you want a dynamic height, you should at least have a way to tell the table view how much height you need by either constraint or delegate method. btw will it be a chance that your other tableview use constraint programmatically?